# Is it possible To host a database for another website hosted elsewhere?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hosting

I have a client that I made a database for. His hosting hosting.xo sucks and I don't know how to build or work on a database using his hosting. Could I point his site to use the database that I have on my hosting account?

Answer (score 1):

If the database server is set up to accept external connections and there is no firewall blocking it, it is certainly possible.

That is often not set up that way for security reasons though.  Doing so would allow direct attacks on your DBMS which can impact its performance and eventually allow intrusions.

Using a remote database also causes a greater load on the network connection since the connection is used for both the data exchange with the database as well as the client connections.